# how to send message between activities in android

Tags: android

My app works as follow: User hits a compose button and types a message then it sends it to the main activity with the date and time in a recycler view with the swipe to refresh much like facebook or any other type of social media. The problem I'm having is that I'm fairly new to android development and haven't seen anything on the google site.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- send your data in the intent:

Use this to "put" the file...

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
String keyIdentifer  = null;
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
```

Then, to retrieve the value try something like:

```
String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
    }
} else {
    newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```

- use event bus to register and handle events with more advanced data and callbacks:
  example of use https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md

Comment: Is there a downside to using `getIntent().getStringExtra("myString")` as opposed to `getIntent.getExtras().getString("myString")`?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can try to use EvenBus library(there are several implementations).
It is so easy to pass message within activity and not only activity. Here is simple example.

```
public class MessageEvent {
    private String message;
    private Date date;
    public MessageEvent(String message,Date date){          
        this.date = date;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Date getDate(){
        return this.date;
    }
}
```

And in activity register for listening events

public class MessageHandlerActivity extends Activity {

```
private EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bus.register(this);
}   

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Unregister
    bus.unregister(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

public void onEvent(MessageEvent event){
   // Do whatever you want with you message
}
}

And to notify all subscribers on the bus use following method.

```
 bus.post(event);
```

But please note in this case assumes that activity is running( created), for example if you are using nested fragments or something other. If you need just to change current activity to the new one, you have to follow common approach - use intent with bundle to pass some data required for new activity initialization.
You can read about this in official documentation.
[Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

SendingActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SendingActivity.this, RecievingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName", value);  // pass your values and retrieve them in the other Activity using keyName
startActivity(intent);
```

RecievingActivity

```
 Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if(extras != null)
String data = extras.getString("keyName"); // retrieve the data using keyName
```

Another way to receive the data

```
 String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("AnyKeyName");
```

You can also send objects using `Parcelable`